# How to navigate between tabs in side panels in Pycharm/Intellilj products

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been using Pycharm for a time now and I have set up useful shortcuts for almost every action I need to take in the IDE. Nonetheless, I'm missing a shortcut to navigate tabs in the side panel like VCS. For instance:

[image]

As you can see, the VCS side panel has 4 tabs inside it. I have a shortcut to open that panel, but sometimes I want to see local changes, others the shelf, and when my pre-commit hooks fail, I want the check the console. Is there anyway to automate this movement?

Comment: Did you try tapping double shift or "Command (MacOS)/Control (Linux/Win) - Shift - A" for "all actions" (or check what your shortcut is for that) then type "Local Changes" and you'll see it has no keyboard shortcut assigned, so you can go to Settings -> Keymap and search for the same action, and assign a shortcut; possibly the same goes for all the others that may not have a default shortcut in the keyboard mapping you're using.

Comment: "Select Next/Prevoius Tab" action should work fine in tool windows.

Comment: Uoh, that is actually great! I got it working with the Select next tab shrotcut!! Thanks a lot! Please post it as an answer. The actions panel was also useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tapping Shift twice, or "`Command (MacOS)/Control (Linux/Win) - Shift - A`" for "*all actions*" (or check what your shortcut is for that) then type "*Local Changes*" and you'll see it has no default keyboard shortcut assigned, so you can go to `Settings -> Keymap`, search for the same action, and assign a shortcut; possibly the same goes for all the others that may not have a default shortcut in the keyboard mapping you're using.

Alternatively, as suggested by another user, you can use `"Select Next/Previous Tab"` (which is normally bound to Control/Cmd + Shift + `[` or `]`) but varies from mapping to mapping, so check your keyboard settings to find out.